# preventDefault not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove the tag redirection hyperlink. Currently clicking it opens a modal but I do not want to redirect the browser. I tried `preventDefault` and it does not work for me.

I'm working with C# MVC. It might be that I overload elsewhere? Or are there other solutions to avoid redirecting? As a last resort I would not like to change the element to a `span`, `div` or `button`.

algo.cshtml:

```
<a id="modalAboutButton">Ir a about </a>

<div id="aboutModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal></div>
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#modalAboutButton', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $modal = $('#aboutModal');
        $.get('/About/Index2', function (resp) {
            $modal.html(resp).foundation('reveal', 'open');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: try `$('#modalAboutButton').click(function (e) {`

Comment: return false inside click event

Comment: try adding href='#' for you anchor tag

Comment: Is impossible that this: `<a id="modalAboutButton">Ir a about </a>` redirects to some page, there is no `href` attribute, the link must not make any action even without preventDefault. Maybe you need to see the computed html to see what happens deeply

Answer (score 1):

Simple example

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
```

Js

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("preventDefault");
});
```

[***Fiddle example***](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/895/)

I hope it will help you.